# Dead circuit off of GFI outlet

Tags: electrical

[image]Wiring going into and out of GFCI outlet. The circuit breaker is good and so is the GFCI outlet reset. Outlets that appear to go one direction from the GFI are working while outlets that appear to go another direction from the GFCI are not. I have checked the connections, stabs and screws, on the effected outlets and they appear to be solid. I'm not too familiar with GFCI circuits and assumed that every outlet coming through the GFCI would be daisy chained. Is this the case? If this is not the case, I am assuming that there is an open between the functioning outlets and the dead outlets. One anomaly that I noticed was, with the circuit breaker off, as I was putting an outlet back in place, the bare ground wire touched a pole on the outlet and arced. Am I getting bleed over from another circuit? Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Note that the GFCI outlet is directly next to the breaker box and all outlets appear to be the other side of the outlet.)

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Take a good, clear pic of the wiring as it's attached to the back of the GFCI outlet in question. Also, show the wiring from the back of the outlet leading into the back of the box so we can get an idea of what cables go where. Help us the best you can by identifying which cable(s) go to working downstream outlets and which side are dead. [Edit] these pics into your question (click the "sun & mountain" icon above the edit box) or upload them someplace like imgur.com and someone will edit them into the post for you.

Comment: Thanks, edited a picture into post. Does this show it well enough?

Comment: It appears to me that you've got an extra pair of pig-tails in there. From the top entry cable, you've got the white wire going to the red wire nut. From that nut, one white wire goes down to a yellow wire nut, and from there, I _think_ to the outlet. The white wire that goes from the outlet to the yellow nut could go directly to the red nut, saving some wire and a nut in the box. Same goes for the black coming out of that same cable. If I'm correct, removing them is less fill in the box and fewer connections to come loose.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan, I noticed that too and when I get it all put back together I will take care of that situation.

Answer (score -1):

From your description a line in (the hot or feeder)

The load out (2 circuits going different directions).

Look at your line and load neutrals I see 3 wires on the line and only 2 on the load that will cause issues.

It also looks like one of the black hot’s has damaged insulation but it is a guess as it is fuzzy on my phone.

The line hot and neutrals should be connected on the line 2 wires looks like an extra neutral.

The load outputs should each connect to 2 circuits looks to be 1 short on the neutral.

Or did this get wired with line and load reversed I can’t quite tell on my phone.

Comment: I assumed the 2 wires were from the breaker box and the 3 wires were outgoing to the circuits, is that correct? The insulation looks good on the black wire, I believe that I see what you were looking at in the picture and it's just a shadow.

Comment: Ok but I think I see at the top 3 connections of white the end and I believe the end is the line connection.    the side I believe is the load side so if the single white should go to line and the 2 white go to load I believe they are reversed. I believe I see load on the right this is why I said I believe the neutrals are mis wired. I can’t tell if the single black  wire goes to the same cable as the single white but if they do reverse them because this was what I was trying to state but can only guess at what I see. My last sentence states this.

Comment: Thanks, it is hard to tell but the single white and single black do go to the same cable. I will tend to the Neutrals being mis wired but I am confused as to why the circuits have worked fine for the ten years that I have been in the hosue and now they don,t. I know that strange things can work for no good reason. I will see if this fixes the problem and will report back here to let you know the results.

Comment: Kenny the GFCI could have failed, but a new one would not work if mis wired.